# При HTTP запросе некоторые сайты отвечают 301-м статусом

Tags: ubuntu, http, telnet

Пытаюсь передать запрос, но с некоторыми сайтами всегда получаю статуc `301 Moved Permanently`. Почему так происходит?

```
telnet habrahabr.ru 80

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: habrahabr.ru
```

Comment: Ну отвечают, и что? Переходите, куда просят.

Comment: Это штатное поведение в рамка протоколамх HTTP, на некоторые запросы сервер отвечает вам 301 HTTP-кодом и перенаправляеn вас на другой URL. Пожалуйста опишите какие у вас это вызывайте трудности.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

если бы вы открыли консоль браузера (а не телнет), вкладку network, то увидели бы, что habrahabr.ru редиректит на https версию сайта.

это  одна из причин "почему сайты редиректят", из других - сайт съезжает с домена и/или домен уже не используется для http/https трафика, сумасшедший админ не смог настроить что-нибудь и т.д. причин может быть много, но первая (редирект с http на https) - самая частая для больших сайтов.

сомневаюсь, что вы сможете браузить сайты у которых только https-версия руками через telnet, вам нужно уметь или **ОЧЕНЬ БЫСТРО ПЕЧАТАТЬ**, или использовать что-нибудь типа curl/python/php/любой другой язык программирования / ...браузер.

тем из начинающих, кто хочет изучить как работает проткол http (очень просто) и как его дебажить - советую забить на это дело и изучать работу [http2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tools-for-debugging-testing-and-using-http-2/)

Comment: Если не сложно, можете развить вашу мысль и показать природу 3XX HTTP-кодов? Какое поведение ожидается от 3XX-кодов HTTP? 302, 307?

Comment: Можно подробнее про "очень быстро печатать"?

Comment: @jisecayeyo ну в протоколе https приходится читать и отправлять туда-сюда всякие ключи-сертификаты, это не просто  "GET /", как бы вы их руками отправляли-получали?

Comment: @strangeqargo, а как вообще попробовать через `telnet` попробовать подключиться к `https`?

Comment: `telnet habrahabr.ru 443` (443 это порт https, браузеры автоматически к нему обращаются, когда видят https в ссылке)

Comment: @jisecayeyo а для чего вам telnet? если хотите отладку http - поставьте wireshark

Comment: @strangeqargo, просто ради интереса, пытался передавать запросы, чтобы лучше понять как http работает и столкнулся со всем этим

Comment: @jisecayeyo http скоро уедет на небо. изучайте http/2, он сложнее, но уже поддерживается браузерами

Answer (score 2):

Так происходит потому, что так хочется владельцам сервера. Код 301 означает, что контент перемещён и его новое расположение передано в параметре `Location`. Браузер, получив ответ `301` должен перейти на новое расположение.

Следует учесть, что 301 означает не просто "перемещено", а "перемещено навсегда". Браузер при повторном запросе изначального адреса может даже не обращаться к серверу, а сразу требовать документ из нового местоположения. Есть ещё код 302, который означает "перемещено временно". Этот адрес перехода браузеру запоминать не нужно.

Comment: Как через telnet передать запрос на нужный адрес, чтобы выдало статус 200?

Comment: @jisecayeyo Использовать адрес из `Location`. Но в случае с хабром Вам это не удастся - там SSL, а его в `telnet` руками не сделать.

Comment: @jisecayeyo это зависит от ресурса. Если сервер "захочет" он может вас редиректить на 3XX-кодом на каждый вас запрос. Кода возвращается HTTP-код сильно зависит от сервера (можно сделать так, что вы никогда этот код не получите).